# Determine where each maven dependency(jar) is called and remove unused

Tags: java, maven

The problem:
I have to work on an existing maven project which has a lot of  unnecessary dependencies.
It's source code is too chaotic(really old project) to determine where each dependency is needed.
 Is there a way to check where each dependency is called, so I can remove it, or alter the code to not need this specific dependency without having to go through the entire source code?

Comment: First step is to check via `mvn dependency:analyze` but this is not 100% safe based on DI etc. But a first good step.

Comment: I'm sure a script can be made that lists the import statements of each source file only, and can filter out the ones from the JDK and the application itself. I'd make it a linux shell script for maximum flexibility and online documentation, if you're one Windows you can use Cygwin to run it.

Comment: And a more brute force way which I have also successfully applied: remove the dependency and see which source files no longer compile in your IDE!

Comment: @Gimby That’s almost exactly what the `mvn dependency:analyze` do. However, tt’s more difficult then just filtering imports, you must also find what artifacts (JARs) provides the classes you’re importing. Don’t reinvent the wheel…

Comment: Usually I have no trouble knowing that by looking at the package name to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

mvn dependency:tree to see how each dependency is being pulled in. it will give you a tree view of how each dependency is being used. This is how i remove unwanted dependencies.